# UICollectionView Cells Reordering

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I am trying to reorder my CollectionView Cells. But can't seem to get it past the UILongPressGestureRecognizer. The state goes from Began -> Changed -> Ended. But it's not going to the moveItemAtIndexPath function.
Here is my Code:

```
  func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, moveItemAtIndexPath sourceIndexPath: NSIndexPath,toIndexPath destinationIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

var temp1 = [self.viewThatIsShown.selectionForView?.pageArray.count]

let temp = temp1.removeAtIndex(sourceIndexPath.item)
temp1.insert(temp, atIndex: destinationIndexPath.item)
}
 func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    let layout = self.viewThatIsShown.selectionForView!.rawJSON["pages"].arrayValue[section]["layout"].stringValue

    if layout == "video" || layout == "social-media" {
        return 1
    } else if layout == "pre-list" {
        let dataJSON = self.viewThatIsShown.selectionForView!.rawJSON["pages"].arrayValue[section]["data"]
        return dataJSON["listitems"].arrayValue.count
    }

    let dataSet = self.viewThatIsShown.dataForView!.dataArray[section]

    return min(dataSet.embeddedItemsArray.count, 2)

}
 switch(gesture.state) {

    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Began:
        guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItemAtPoint(gesture.locationInView(self.collectionView)) else {
            break
        }
        collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItemAtIndexPath(selectedIndexPath)
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed:
        collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.locationInView(gesture.view!))
    case UIGestureRecognizerState.Ended:
        collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
    default:
        collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
    }
```

There is no error being shown as well. I think I am making some mistake in counting the number of Items in Section. But can't figure it out.
P.S I have six sections in my UICollectionview which i want to use it for drag and drop section.

Answer (score 0):

It would be very helpful to see the implementation of your UILongPressGestureRecognizer selector, as that is a key part of the puzzle.  In general, though, you'll need to observe the .began, .changed, .ended states, as you mention, and update the position.  One way you can do this is that you can switch on the `gesture.state` and do something like:

```
switch gesture.state {
case .began:
    //Get a reference to the indexPath being pressed
    guard let selectedIndexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: self.collectionView)) else { break }
    //Start interactive movement
    self.collectionView.beginInteractiveMovementForItem(at: selectedIndexPath)
case .changed:
    //Update position based on new gesture location
    self.collectionView.updateInteractiveMovementTargetPosition(gesture.location(in: self.collectionView))
case .ended:
    //End interaction with cell. This will cause moveItemAtIndexPath to fire.
    self.collectionView.endInteractiveMovement()
case .default:
    //Just to cover your bases
    self.collectionView.cancelInteractiveMovement()
}
```

Comment: Is the problem that the `moveItemAtIndexPath` function isn't being executed at all, or that it's just not doing anything?  The code inside that function effectively does nothing at all - it creates an array containing a single, optional `Int`, removes that value, and then puts the value back.  Nothing in there will affect your `collectionView` or the datasource for it.

Comment: Hi, Yeah the collectionView is moving. But no i want to move the ReusableColectionCells which i have as well. Is it possible to move them? I have 6sections in my CollectionView. I want to move those. Is it possible?